# How to convert .mat binary format to 2D numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, mat-file

I'm converting [hand_dataset](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/data/hands/) annotations to such a format I could use it in YOLOv3. Annotations are in .mat binary format and I want to extract it, convert and reorganize in .csv.

I have tried `mat = scipy.io.loadmat(file)`, but extracting data goes in strange format.

```py
mat = scipy.io.loadmat(file)
bboxes = np.transpose(mat['boxes'])
```

Gives output:

```
[[array([[(array([[488.42954942, 345.62261032]]), array([[461.57045058, 348.37738968]]), array([[465.57045058, 387.37738968]]), array([[492.42954942, 384.62261032]]))]],
      dtype=[('a', 'O'), ('b', 'O'), ('c', 'O'), ('d', 'O')])]
```

where shape is `(2,1)` and numpy.array type.

I am capable to extract points iterating over whole dataset annotations like that:
`points = np.array([point[0] for point in bboxes[0][0][0][0]])`

Where hierarchy is:

```
print(bboxes[0])
print(bboxes[0][0])
print(bboxes[0][0][0])
print(bboxes[0][0][0][0])
print(bboxes[0][0][0][0][0])
print(bboxes[0][0][0][0][0][0][1])
```

Is there any "nicer" way to extract needed points?

Output from given prints:

```
[[(array([[488.42954942, 345.62261032]]), array([[461.57045058, 348.37738968]]), array([[465.57045058, 387.37738968]]), array([[492.42954942, 384.62261032]]))]]
[(array([[488.42954942, 345.62261032]]), array([[461.57045058, 348.37738968]]), array([[465.57045058, 387.37738968]]), array([[492.42954942, 384.62261032]]))]
(array([[488.42954942, 345.62261032]]), array([[461.57045058, 348.37738968]]), array([[465.57045058, 387.37738968]]), array([[492.42954942, 384.62261032]]))
[[488.42954942 345.62261032]]
345.6226103157693
```

Any help would be appreciate! Thanks!

Comment: There's a `squeeze` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I can recreate your array with

```
In [38]: array=np.array 
In [43]: data = np.zeros((1,1),object)                                          
In [44]: data[0,0] = array([[(array([[488.42954942, 345.62261032]]), array([[461
    ...: .57045058, 348.37738968]]), array([[465.57045058, 387.37738968]]), arra
    ...: y([[492.42954942, 384.62261032]]))]], 
    ...:       dtype=[('a', 'O'), ('b', 'O'), ('c', 'O'), ('d', 'O')])          
In [45]: data                                                                   
Out[45]: 
array([[array([[(array([[488.42954942, 345.62261032]]), array([[461.57045058, 348.37738968]]), array([[465.57045058, 387.37738968]]), array([[492.42954942, 384.62261032]]))]],
      dtype=[('a', 'O'), ('b', 'O'), ('c', 'O'), ('d', 'O')])]],
      dtype=object)
```

This is a (1,1) object dtype array, that contains another array.  That array is also (1,1) shape, but with a compound dtype (a `structured` array).

```
In [51]: data.shape, data.dtype                                                 
Out[51]: ((1, 1), dtype('O'))
```

In MATLAB everything is 2d.  `loadmat` has a `squeeze` parameter that can tell it to remove the unnecessary dimensions.  Without that we get a lot of (1,1) shaped arrays.

MATLAB objects like `cell` and `struct` are returned as object dtype arrays of some sort. Regular MATLAB matrices are returned an numeric `numpy` arrays.

We can extract the one element from `data` with a 2d index (more idiomatic than `data[0][0]`):

```
In [52]: data1 = data[0,0]                                                      
In [53]: data1.shape, data1.dtype                                               
Out[53]: ((1, 1), dtype([('a', 'O'), ('b', 'O'), ('c', 'O'), ('d', 'O')]))
```

`item()` also works to remove the one item from an array:

```
In [54]: data.item().dtype                                                      
Out[54]: dtype([('a', 'O'), ('b', 'O'), ('c', 'O'), ('d', 'O')])
```

At this level the array is a structured array with 4 (named) fields, each object dtype.

Fields are (normally) indexed by name.  But being object dtype we have yet another layer:

```
In [74]: data1['a']                                                             
Out[74]: array([[array([[488.42954942, 345.62261032]])]], dtype=object)
In [75]: data1['a'].item()                                                      
Out[75]: array([[488.42954942, 345.62261032]])
In [76]: data1['a'].item().squeeze()                                            
Out[76]: array([488.42954942, 345.62261032])
```

@aparpara's idea of using to `tolist()` may be the cleanest way of extracting those nested object fields:

```
In [85]: data1.tolist()                                                         
Out[85]: 
[[(array([[488.42954942, 345.62261032]]),
   array([[461.57045058, 348.37738968]]),
   array([[465.57045058, 387.37738968]]),
   array([[492.42954942, 384.62261032]]))]]
```

On a structured array `tolist()` creates a list (or nested list) of tuples, one tuple per 'record' of array.

Then we can use `np.array` or `concatenate` to join the arrays into one, and `squeeze` to remove excess dimensions:

```
In [87]: np.array(data1.tolist()).squeeze()                                     
Out[87]: 
array([[488.42954942, 345.62261032],
       [461.57045058, 348.37738968],
       [465.57045058, 387.37738968],
       [492.42954942, 384.62261032]])
```

The MATLAB source isn't a simple 2d numeric matrix. So the translation to a different language isn't going to be simple either.  Some `loadmat` parameters can simplify the return structure.  Beyond that we have to work our way down through layers, with `item` or `[0,0]` kind of indexing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was looking for answer like this! Just got lost in some other forums with MATLAB format, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should give a nicer result:

```
np.concatenate(bboxes[0][0].tolist()).squeeze()
```